# How to use jquery to select all the children of an element as well as all images

Tags: jquery

```
$('img, div.name < *')
```

Only returns the first children but i need all of them. I can do it in two statements, but i need to do it in one since i want to :not the expression.

```
:not ( $('div.name').children() + $('img') )
```

Is what i'm trying to achieve.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to select descendants, not just direct children, use `*`

```
$('img, div.name *')
```

`>` will only get you the direct children of that object, but it might not matter

Comment: this only selects the children but it's on the right path. $('img,div.name, div.name *') works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.name > *, img');
```

should do it.

Comment: only selects the direct children

Comment: @montrealmike: I thought that was exactly what you are after.

Comment: @montrealmike: "direct children" is redundant. If they're nested deeper, they're not children.

Comment: I agree, but that's what jQuery writes about the `>` selector. "Description: Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent"."